# How do I alter the "slanted/tilted view" of my QGIS Project?

Tags: qgis

Version 2.14.14 (Essen) - I originally had a flat/2D/birds-eye view of my layers (all ESRI Shapefiles/Vector Layers) - please see the first image attached ([image: Original]).  However, I altered something without realising/remembering and now my view of the layers is slanted/tilted - please see the second image ([image: Unintended View]).  How can I alter the view back to the original 2D/birds-eye view?  Is it something to do with the coordinate system or projection of layers?  I do apologise if it's something really obvious.

Comment: You've probably changed the project's CRS.

Comment: Seems to by the CRS. 
Do you have maybe the original files to check the CRS there and compare it with the current one? Maybe it is just an  OTF projection change?

Comment: @AlexPB You should post that as an answer (explaining how the CRS was accidentally changed, and how to change it back) for future users of this site.